# Clients got IP-addresses from DHCP but can't reach Internet

Tags: networking, iptables, netplan, hostapd, dhcpd

I'm trying to build home router from device with two ethernet ports (`enp2s0` and `enp3s0`) and WiFI (`wlo2`), based on Ubuntu Server 22.

Everything is set, clients can connect via wifi to the router (it's IP Address `192.168.1.1`), can get their IP addresses (`192.168.1.11` and `192.168.1.12`). But they have no internet access. And also each client can ping each other, but pinging the router always fails.

Can't understand what to do, because no error happens and DHCP and NAT works fine.

Configs:

`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      ignore-carrier: true
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlo2:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
      access-points:
        "TestNetwork":
          password: "myTestNetwork123"
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.200;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.1.1;
}
```

`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

```
INTERFACESv4="enp2s0 wlo2"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlo2
driver=nl80211
ssid=TestNetwork
hw_mode=g 
channel=1
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=myTestNetwork123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

`/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Traffic forwarding enabled with

```
sudo echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

`/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

```
*filter
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -I enp2s0 -o enp3s0 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -I wlo2 -o enp3s0 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -I enp3s0 -o enp2s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -I enp3s0 -o wlo2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT 

*nat 
-A POSTROUTING -o $WAN_INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
```

Sysctl set with

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" | tee /etc/sysctl.conf
```

All services works. No errors found.

Comment: If you are on the router, can you ping a client - 192.168.1.10 or 11?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do that. Pinging clients from router fails also.

It confuses me. Cause, `.10` can ping `.11` and `.11` can ping `.10`. But `.1` can't ping both. And both can't ping `.1`. 

I'm novice in networks, but maybe it means something: `enp3s0` has another subnet, that was assigned automatically – `192.168.2`.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip route` to your question. I suspect the route to `192.168.1/24` goes through `enp2s0`, whereas your clients are on `wlo2`. You will need to either put `enp2s0` in a different subnet, or join `enp2s0` and `wlo2` on a bridge. You now have two interfaces in one alleged subnet, but it's not actually a subnet: it is split in the middle by your router.

Comment: @zwets you're right. The Internet connection appears after moving `wlo2` to subnet `192.168.3`. Now both interfaces – `enp2s0` and `wlo2` – have connection.

The problem is that I want to see them in one subnet)) Because I need, that devices with ethernet and wifi connection can communicate with each other. I have TP Link Deco router, that allows such thing. So how can I do that? 

I tried to create bridge connection between `enp2s0` and `wlo2`, but got error `Can’t add wlo2 to bridge br0: Operation not supported`

Comment: For your clients to reach each other you don't need the bridge. There are two options: route between subnets, or bridge into one subnet. How to resolve the bridge issue is a new question.

Comment: Spent one more day with experiments. In total, bridge or different subnet is the correct answer. I'm using bridge now.